# Inline code tags are rendered as text under some circumstances

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

In my aspx I have this line:

```
<link href="<%= Request.ApplicationPath %>/css/ma/screen-ma.css"        rel="Stylesheet"type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

which renders as:

```
<link href="/XFormPortal/css/ma/screen-ma.css"        rel="Stylesheet"type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

That seems correct, right?

Then i change a single character, lets say add a space between the rel and the type attribute, so now I have the following:

```
<link href="<%= Request.ApplicationPath %>/css/ma/screen-ma.css"        rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Which now rendes as:

```
<link href="&lt;%= Request.ApplicationPath %>/css/ma/screen-ma.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Okay, what just happend here? The inline code tag is suddenly ignored and written out as text? Because of a single space?

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link href=<%="\""+Request.ApplicationPath%>/css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

Comment: this should also be equivalent... <link href="~/css" .../>

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest it has something to do with the order in which expressions are parsed by the precompiler... specifically, I suspect that the omission of the space in your first example causes a particular regular expression match to fail, and you essentially escape correct parsing. Use single quotes around your **href** tag instead.

Comment: That made no difference. Good suggestion though!

Comment: Interesting.. I've also found that it doesn't matter which space you omit, as long as you omit one ;-) ... which led me to:

<link href=<%="\""+Request.ApplicationPath%>/css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>

(include the opening quote in your inline emitter.

Comment: That seems to work! Thanks for taking the time to shed some light on this issue which I hope will be a help for other people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the runat="server" from the head tag..